# publishing the resource files of another project to context path instead of jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

I've few common resource files, like base JS, CSS files and HTML files and those files will be used by two maven projects/modules. I've moved these files to a common project & included that as a dependency to both projects. The common project is published as a jar files and I don't want to serve the files from jar file (using ClassLoader' stuff).

Is there a way to make the common project resource copied as it is into the actual project context folder, like:

`COMMON_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/login.html` to `WEBAPP1/src/main/webapp`
`COMMON_PROJECT/src/main/webapp/login.html` to `WEBAPP2/src/main/webapp`

***Actual requirement***: I don't want to publish the common files as a jar file because later those files will be moved out of war file and placed directly in Ngnix server. Can some provide the guidelines for better management in this perspective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with the plugin answered by @Eugene Kuleshov, but the plugin is having dependency issues with the latest m2e version.

After some search, [m2e-wtp](https://github.com/sonatype/m2eclipse-wtp/) plugin (update site: `http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/m2eclipse-wtp/`) is supporting the exact web-overlay feature.

This requires the latest [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) plugin (1.0 +) (update site: `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/`)

After installing the `m2e-wtp`, we need to install the `buildhelper` lifecycle mapper from `m2e` catalog

- `Window > Preferences > Maven > Discovery > Open Catalog`
- install `Lifecycle mappings > buildhelper`

Only in the latest versions of these `m2e` and `m2e-wtp` plugins, weboverlays are supported (the old Maven builder we see in the `Project properties > Builders` is not capable of doing that)

However, with the normal Maven build, overlays work out of the box. By default, Maven war plugin *(not eclipse plugin)* will copy the resource files from dependency war (also jar) in to the context path when we Maven build the project. `overlay` are required if we want more control on this process, like some excluding.

Answer (score 2):

With Maven, you can make your common project an [overlay project](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) declared as dependency, so its resources can be shared in other projects. You will have to use the latest m2eclipse plugin with WTP integration to [support overlays in Eclipse IDE](http://printstacktrace.org/blog/2010/01/demo-of-m2eclipse-with-waroverlay/).

Comment: Thanks. I m getting `Missing requirement: Extensions for m2eclipse and eclipse webtools 0.1.0.201004101956 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.ext.feature.feature.group 0.1.0.201004101956) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp [0.10.0,0.11.0)' but it could not be found` when installing the plugin and I tried with some legacy version as said in some issue, but with no luck. Any help?

Comment: your comment showed me right direction and ended up with searching for new versions of `m2e` and `m2e-wtp` plugins. I've added the details as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can provide your resources files as war project.
And then use the [Warpath Plugin](http://static.appfuse.org/maven-warpath-plugin/) to make your two project import the war (and its resources).

Comment: with this plugin, will building from Eclipse also publish the overlays?

Comment: Never tried from the IDE. I just add to change configuration files. New files and overriding ones are in the generated war.